# is there any possible way to export xml data from a pdf using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to export pdf files to xml like this format

```
  <w:p>
<w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="Heading5"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="20" w:name="ssdfsdfd"/>
<w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">Ssdfsdfd</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="20"/>
```

so that i can not miss fonts and images.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer).

Or [pypdf2xml](https://github.com/zejn/pypdf2xml), a project base on pdfminer.